# Selected option from the dropdown list is not fetching the option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the following HTML code to create a dropdown list of VF pages:

```
<div id="vp_page_dd">
   <span></span>
   <button type="button"  id="btnSort" >
      <table width="100%">
         <tr>
            <td width="81%" id="BtnDropDown_test"><select id= "VFPageListsDropDown123" class="menuDropDown"></select></td>
            <td width="19%"> <span class="caret"></span></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </button>
   <span>
      <!--  <div id="dropdowns-1" class="dropdowns dropdowns-tip">
         <ul class="dropdowns-menu" id="VFPageListsDropDown"></ul>
         </div> -->
   </span>
</div>
```

When I choose a option from the list, it gets selected but the value of the option(which is a particular page) is not displayed and the default page still covers the screen.
To get a particular page I am using the following code:

```
$('#VFPageListsDropDown123').change(function() {
            var selectedPageOption = $('#VFPageListsDropDown123').val();
            if (selectedPageOption === "Pages") {
                var selectedVFPage = selectedPageOption
                setSelectedVFPageActive(selectedVFPage);
                console.log(" inside drop down click(): " + jsonfileURL);
                getOneVFpage(jsonfileURL, selectedVFPage);
```

The setSelectedVFPage function is as follows:

```
function setSelectedVFPageActive(selectedVFPage) {
   document.getElementById("SelectedVFPageActive").value = selectedVFPage;
   console.log("current Active VF page set to 2 (setSelectedVFPageActive) : " + document.getElementById("SelectedVFPageActive").value);
   return selectedVFPage;
}
```

Bootstrap converts a table inside div into list.That is how the options are being fetched.

The code which I am providing may not be enough for you people to give me an answer, but I just want to know that where I am doing a mistake in writing the function which fetches the corresponding page? Please tell even if you have a rough idea of what I should do to get the page.

Comment: where are the options of select#VFPageListsDropDown123

Comment: It is difficult to know what the problem is with the code you have given. Is it possible to post the setSlectedVFPageActive() function contents? Also as Ramesh has pointed out, it would be useful to know what the options in your dropdown are. You could try and add a console.log() into your code inside the if statement to check that the value is being matched.

Comment: `table` inside a `button`?!!!